# Alternatives to dynamic sql in stored function

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

I'm writing a stored function where I calculate the position of a cell, which value I need to select from a table. To do this, I decided to save this position in a variable, in order to use it as the offset of a LIMIT clause.

According to my research, the way of using values set into local variables with the LIMIT statement is through a prepared statement, but I also got that prepared statements (nor any dynamic SQL) are allowed in stored functions. Are there any alternatives to solve my problem?

A simplified example of my situation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(a int) RETURNS decimal DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
     SET @var1 := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table);
     SET @var2 := (ROUND(@var1 * a/5))
     PREPARE STMT FROM 'RETURN (SELECT * FROM other_table LIMIT ?, ?)';
     EXECUTE STMT USING @var2, @var1;
END
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Ideally, this would get me the result I need, where I need it. But, of course, I get Error Code 1336 saying "Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger"

Comment: Please stop calling this a UDF. MySQL calls this a [stored function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html). MySQL's term [UDF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html) is for code modules written in C and loaded into mysqld as shared libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need dynamic SQL for this stored function. You don't need to use dynamic SQL for a LIMIT clause. You just need to make sure the variables are `INT` type, not strings.

Here's a quick demo:

```
create function foo(a int) returns int reads sql data 
begin 
  return (select x from test limit 1 offset a); 
end
```

Notice several other things:

- Use `READS SQL DATA` instead of `DETERMINISTIC`. Your function is not deterministic. You should read the manual page on create function to understand these options better.
- Don't use `SELECT *`. A function can only return a single scalar value, not a set of columns. The table you are querying might in fact have one column, but it's a good habit to make queries be more clear.
- Using `LIMIT` with no `ORDER BY` may surprise you later, because it doesn't guarantee which order it will use for determining the offset. It's best if you use `ORDER BY` explicitly.
- When using `LIMIT`, I think it's more clear to use `LIMIT <count> OFFSET <offset>` instead of `LIMIT <offset>, <count>`. They do the same thing, but it's easier to remember which argument is which.
- Your LIMIT query appears to be selecting many rows. You need the query to select exactly one column and one row, or else it's not valid to return from a stored function.